# Caption problem

Tags: captions

I'm writing some notes and I get the following error when I add the figure caption:

```
Illegal parameter number in definition of reservad@a
<to be read again>
\crcr
```

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{pic.png}
\caption{\overrightarrow{\mathbf{AB}}}\label{some-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphicx, tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
%\includegraphics[width=.7\textwidth]{pic.png}
\caption{$\protect\overrightarrow{\mathbf{AB}}$}\label{some-label}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]